# Website is building normally but not during publish

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, publish, loadcontrol

I have developed a usercontrol in ASP.NET and used LoadControl to dynamically add the control to a page. When I want to read the usercontrol data (properties) I cast page control to its type like this:

```
 ((ASP.ucMultiSelectCallback)crtl)
```

The website is building and working correctly but when I want to Publish the website , during its automatic build action, it faces error on the line of code I mentioned. The Error is

> " the type or namespace does not exist ,are you missing an assembly
>   reference "

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a probmel in compiled code. Be sure that when you test application it uses "Release" mode, because I think you publish and release mode.